# Catching anchor element using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Tags: vba, web-scraping, htmlelements

I want to catch the anchor element in website via vba.

I tried both as an MSHTML.IHTMLAnchorElement and MSHMTL.IHTMLBUttonELement but either way gives an error on Set line. Can anyone describe what's wrong with code below?

```
Sub goToWhtSpp()

    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://cooperatordirectory.com/"

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy
    Loop

    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Set doc = ie.document
    Application.Wait 3000
    
    URL = "https://cooperatordirectory.com/search_results?location_value=Florida&adm_lvl_1_sn=FL&stateSearchLN=Florida&country_sn=US&location_type=administrative_area_level_1&stateSearch=FL&swlat=24.396308&nelat=31.000968&swlng=-87.634896&nelng=-79.974306&lat=27.6648274&lng=-81.5157535&faddress=Florida%2C+USA&place_id=ChIJvypWkWV2wYgR0E7HW9MTLvc"
    ie.navigate URL


Dim aelement As MSHTML.IHTMLAnchorElement
Set aelement = doc.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-block") ' err line

Dim btn As MSHTML.IHTMLButtonElement
Set btn = doc.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-block") ' err line
Debug.Print btn.Value
End Sub


<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="/pro/20220324090906/connect">Send Message</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a page load wait after each `.navigate`. In this case you only need the one `.navigate` and wait.

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection not a single node. So both your type declaration, subsequent `SET` attempt to this type, and later attempt to view the `.value` attribute will fail. `.value` is a property of a single node.

If you want the first "button" href then index into a correctly typed variable and call `.item(0)`, or, more efficiently, use the `querySelector()` method of `ie.document` and pass in a single class of the multi-valued class (the one which still correctly identifies the target element).

---

```
Dim anchors As IHTMLElementCollection
Set anchors = .document.getElementsByClassName("btn-primary")

Dim anchor As IHTMLAnchorElement
Set anchor = .document.getElementsByClassName("btn-primary").Item(0)
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrintMessageUrl()
    
    Const URL As String = "https://cooperatordirectory.com/search_results?location_value=Florida&adm_lvl_1_sn=FL&stateSearchLN=Florida&country_sn=US&location_type=administrative_area_level_1&stateSearch=FL&swlat=24.396308&nelat=31.000968&swlng=-87.634896&nelng=-79.974306&lat=27.6648274&lng=-81.5157535&faddress=Florida%2C+USA&place_id=ChIJvypWkWV2wYgR0E7HW9MTLvc"
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Debug.Print .document.querySelector(".btn-primary").href
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am taking your answer as right. But I need to improve your code. Because of your code i  looked for querySelector locators issue and I found what I need. .document.querySelector(".module.nomargin.text-center > a").className

Comment: I want to take the next one, , but cannot index(1) it gives me an error

Comment: `.document.querySelectorAll(".btn-primary").item(1).href`

Comment: Thanks. But cannot get into. Trying on my own, on your code with              Set a = .document.querySelector("div.module a")
        Debug.Print a.innerText

        Debug.Print a.querySelectorAll("div.module a")

Comment: `Debug.Print .querySelectorAll("div.module a").item(1).innerText`

Comment: Assuming your selector list returns more than one much i.e. `.querySelectorAll("div.module a").Length > 1`

Comment: I want to see intelli-sense after dot notation querySelector, even though I have declared Dim document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument it doesnot give me any showups(there is not IHTMLQueryCollection or element). Could you help with it also

Comment: It gives error of 438, Object does not support this method     Debug.Print .querySelectorAll("div.module a").item(1).innerText

Comment: I have no issue with running this. See `https://pastebin.com/54FQHX1a`

Comment: I had not document before querySelector(). I added nowit works. Explain me please how your code can work if querySelector is HTML element and we have not declared it DIM document As MSHTML.HTMLDOcument...Though it works..?

Comment: `.document`  is referencing the IE instance and as such is the document node of IE not an `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` variable. The "." is referencing the parent object reference held by the `With` block. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement